# Parentheses in text mode around multiple lines

Tags: brackets, text-mode

I would like to enclose multiple lines of text (not in math mode) around parentheses (like in the image). How could i do that?

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1):

`$\left(\parbox{.9\textwidth}{text text text text text }\right)$`